# admob-free interstitial close event ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

Working with [Admob-free plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free/).

How to fire interstitial close event,

```
//this is the code found for javscript
document.addEventListener('admob.interstitial.events.CLOSE', function (event) {
    console.log(event)
    admob.interstitial.prepare()
})
//i want this code  in ionic3
```

can someone help how to do this in typescript/ ionic3

document.addEventListener is showing error in typescript

Comment: please give the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import {Component, Renderer} from '@angular/core';    
constructor(renderer: Renderer) {

            renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'admob.interstitial.events.CLOSE', (event) => {
                console.log(event);
            });

        }
```

you can do it like this

Answer (score 1):

simply the best way to do it is simply as the below, but don't forget to register **AdmobFree** in the constructor

```
constructor(
    private admobFree: AdMobFree,
    public platform: Platform
) {

    // Handle interstitial's close event
    this.admobFree.on('admob.interstitial.events.CLOSE').subscribe(() => {
       // handle interstitial close
    });
}
```